# nonincremental update requires all .SBR files

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working in .net platform . I am using VS 2013. 
After building I am getting error like 
nonincremental update requires all .SBR files

Comment: There is not enough information in your question, so we cannot help you. Please read the [ask] topics to get informed how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four options:

1. Clean solution then build solution.
2. Go to the bin folder. Search all *.pdb files and delete them.
3. Delete the entire bin folder and rebuild your solution.
4. `Remove the <BrowseFileInformation></BrowseFileInformation> line in the .vcproj file.`

Comment: Can you explain option 4? How would deleting a random line help? Especially in a file that a C#/WPF project does not have by default?

Comment: Remove  <BrowseFileInformation> </BrowseFileInformation> line in the .vcproj file

Comment: your fourth option worked .